# I want to get my HDD back under /

Tags: server, partitioning, hard-drive

Hi I have server that I can only access via CLI. It came to me preconfigured and has 8TB of HDD but I can use only 4TB as it has raid1 configuration on it. I have backed up my data and I need all my HDD back so that I can use it.

[image]

Comment: which OS is that?

Comment: Its ubuntu and I can only access it via cli

Comment: You need to free up space, if you add all those numbers up it is 4TB, root alone adds up to 3.48TB, add the rest and you have 4TB, its just seperated.